# Marketing Cloud Fuel SDK API : get DataExtension/List related to Email, get Contact info from those DataExtension/List

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, fuel-sdk, python

I am working on Salesforce Marketing Cloud API to extract Email Receiver Contact detail. For that I used below approach.

**Step 1 :  Extract List related to Email (used ET_ListSend()) using below code.I am extracting List from email as I couldn't find Data Extension Api that can get Data Extension used in email send.**

event.search_filter =  {'Property' :'SendID', 'SimpleOperator' : 'equals', 'Value' : '4491471'}

event.auth_stub = myClient

getResponse = event.get()

**Step 2 : Extract Contact from List (used ET_List())**

event.search_filter =  {'Property' : 'ID', 'SimpleOperator' : 'equals', 'Value' : '7281'}

event.auth_stub = myClient

getResponse = event.get()

Below are the problems I am facing in data extraction.

**Problem 1** : When I get List Related to email it is showing "All Subscriber" list most of the time even though Data Extension used in Email is not "All Subscriber". So When I get get contact related to that "All Subscriber"  using code in step 2 it gives me all contact info and not specific contacts who received that email.

**Problem 2** : Some of the list I get(using step1 code) are named  "VPL 7285 for List 7281" (7285,7281 -change based on email). Again this name is not same as the name of Data Extension used in email. When I get contacts from that list it gives empty list.

Can anyone please help me with this and let me know what is correct way to get contacts-assigned data extension form specific email in Marketing Cloud?